# How does parameterized constructor and functional object invocation work together?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

In the code below, consider the transform function. The functional object passed to it is Add(10). This implies Add a = Add(10) or Add a = 10 is valid.
 From my understanding, Add(10) calls the constructor with one parameter and _v will be initialized to the values of the vector.So initially before performing a + _v the value of _v is the content of vector. After addition the value of vector will be incremented by 10.

Can anyone please clarify how will the constructor be called and how does the function operator()(int a) get called?

Code:

```
struct Add
{
    int _v;
    Add(int v) : _v(v) {}
    int operator()(int a)
    {
       cout<<a; 
        return a + _v;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int t[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    vector<int> v1(t, t + 10);
    list<int> l1(v1.size());
    //Add a = Add(10);
    cout << "Source collection:\n";
    cout << "v1: "; for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), print<int>); cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Adding value - 10 to all the elements of the collection:\n";
    transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), l1.begin(), Add(10));
    cout << "l1: "; for_each(l1.begin(), l1.end(), print<int>); cout << endl << endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Output:
Source collection:
v1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Adding value - 10 to all the elements of the collection:

12345678910 l1: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

Comment: Look up how constructors work. Then look up how call operators work.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] Add(10) calls the constructor with one parameter and *_v will be initialized to the values of the vector*. [...]

Nope! `_v` will be initialized to the values passed as parameter in the constructor. In your case `10`.

So you will construct an object (instance of the struct `Add`) and its *variable member* (`_v`) is initialized to `10`.

When the function object is called (see [operators overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)) then it takes and `int` and return that `int` plus the value stored in `_v` (*10* in your case).

The standard function [transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) works in this way:

```
transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), l1.begin(), Add(10));
```

Takes some inputs, apply they a function (transformation) and store the transformed object in some output.

In your case:

- Takes a *input range*, in this case all the vector `v1` (`// from v1.begin to v2.end`).
- Takes an *output iterator* (where the transformed element will be placed), in your case you're just storing the transformed element of the vector into the list `l1`.
- Takes a function which perform a transformation. In your case the function is *object function*, an instance of `Add(10)`. So the `operator()` is call for each element of the vector (that's why the `operator()` of `Add` take integer as input parameters) and return a new integer `x + 10`.

In short, each integer of the vector is transformed by the `operator()` of `Add` object which gives and sums 10 to it.